# Followers don't stay dressed in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Im on Xbox, for any follower I have, Housecarl, Steward, no matter what I give them, they don't stay dressed, I made Uthgerd my house steward, and she wear's steel plate armor, so I give her Daedric armor, and they put it on for the moment, I let her leave my service, she still has it on, but whenever I leave the room, it seems something about a loading screen makers her go back to her other armor, and she doesn't put her better Daedric armor back on until I trade with her and take something or add something random to her inventory, then it "Refreshes" I guess you could say. I've been spending forever crafting Daedric and Dragon armor for my Housecarls and Stewards because I want awesome guards patrolling my house, but the fact they wont wear it once I leave, kinda ruins all my efforts, and is a complete waste of all the materials I've spent. Any weapon I give them stays on them, and they use it, I've even pick pocketed their default armor and it end up coming right back into their inventory.

Answer (score 2):

NPCs that aren't currently following you will re-equip their default armor after you re-enter their cell. There is no way to change this behavior except for mods.

Comment: Is it the same with spouses? i'm unsure if it's the "Spouses can live anywhere" mod but there was a dialog option with Lydia after i married her saying "there's something i want to tell you..." and in there there are a bunch of options to change her appearance, using her best gear (she has all Deadric armour so she wears that), her housecarl armor or casual cloth

Comment: @Memor-X as long as your spouse isn't following you, yes.

Comment: Do you know any mod for keep the dress of the followers? I want my followers to wear their armors

Comment: @JCalcines I haven't used it, but the following mod claims to do it http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=15925